# Events via Google Calendar API have wrong time

Tags: google-calendar-api

My boss has this event on Calendar site

[image]

id: 6goj0c9h6hh38bb2cos32b9k61j3gb9o75imab9ickp62p1o74rjgdr46s_R20230406T143000

Link: https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NmdvajBjOWg2aGgzOGJiMmNvczMyYjlrNjFqM2diOW83NWltYWI5aWNrcDYycDFvNzRyamdkcjQ2c18yMDIzMDQwNlQxNDMwMDBaIHJvbmVua21hbkBt

It is supposed to start at 19:15 Israel time. He said he probably updated the event 4 days ago, by changing the start/end times (it was at another time, now it is at 19:15).

But from the API i get the result below when fetching the event, which starts at 17:30 instead, so it's not even a problem with timezones. Could be that the update done a few days ago is not taken into account by the API ??
If anyone can help me figure out, would be appreciated thanks.

```
Google\Service\Calendar\Event Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => recurrence
    [anyoneCanAddSelf] =>
    [attachmentsType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventAttachment
    [attachmentsDataType:protected] => array
    [attendeesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventAttendee
    [attendeesDataType:protected] => array
    [attendeesOmitted] =>
    [colorId] =>
    [conferenceDataType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\ConferenceData
    [conferenceDataDataType:protected] =>
    [created] => 2023-02-22T07:13:30.000Z
    [creatorType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventCreator
    [creatorDataType:protected] =>
    [description] =>
    [endType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [endDataType:protected] =>
    [endTimeUnspecified] =>
    [etag] => "3359659681366000"
    [eventType] => default
    [extendedPropertiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventExtendedProperties
    [extendedPropertiesDataType:protected] =>
    [gadgetType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventGadget
    [gadgetDataType:protected] =>
    [guestsCanInviteOthers] =>
    [guestsCanModify] =>
    [guestsCanSeeOtherGuests] =>
    [hangoutLink] =>
    [htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NmdvajBjOWg2aGgzOGJiMmNvczMyYjlrNjFqM2diOW83NWltYWI5aWNrcDYycDFvNzRyamdkcjQ2c18yMDIzMDQwNlQxNDMwMDBaIHJvbmVua21hbkBt
    [iCalUID] => 6goj0c9h6hh38bb2cos32b9k61j3gb9o75imab9ickp62p1o74rjgdr46s_R20230406T143000@google.com
    [id] => 6goj0c9h6hh38bb2cos32b9k61j3gb9o75imab9ickp62p1o74rjgdr46s_R20230406T143000
    [kind] => calendar#event
    [location] =>
    [locked] =>
    [organizerType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventOrganizer
    [organizerDataType:protected] =>
    [originalStartTimeType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [originalStartTimeDataType:protected] =>
    [privateCopy] =>
    [recurrence] => Array
        (
            [0] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO
        )

    [recurringEventId] =>
    [remindersType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminders
    [remindersDataType:protected] =>
    [sequence] => 0
    [sourceType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventSource
    [sourceDataType:protected] =>
    [startType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [startDataType:protected] =>
    [status] => confirmed
    [summary] => תפוס
    [transparency] =>
    [updated] => 2023-03-26T11:24:00.683Z
    [visibility] =>
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [creator] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventCreator Object
        (
            [displayName] =>
            [email] => <stripped>@gmail.com
            [id] =>
            [self] => 1
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [organizer] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventOrganizer Object
        (
            [displayName] =>
            [email] => <stripped>@gmail.com
            [id] =>
            [self] => 1
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [start] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime Object
        (
            [date] =>
            [dateTime] => 2023-04-06T17:30:00+03:00
            [timeZone] => Asia/Jerusalem
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [end] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime Object
        (
            [date] =>
            [dateTime] => 2023-04-06T21:00:00+03:00
            [timeZone] => Asia/Jerusalem
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [reminders] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminders Object
        (
            [collection_key:protected] => overrides
            [overridesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminder
            [overridesDataType:protected] => array
            [useDefault] => 1
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

This is not about timezones

Comment: Might be related to the DST date change for this year. I'd highly recommend you to contact [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for support of this inconsistency if you have a GW account, or maybe you could report it using https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support#developer_product_feedback

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa Upvoted for the links. But about DST no, how can it be? The difference with the expected result, in this case is 1h 45m. If DST was to blame, the difference would be either 1 hour or nothing . There may be time zones with 1h45m shift during DST, but this timezone is not the case.